# Модальное окно в месте клика

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, bootstrap

Требуется сделать модальные окна с позиционированием в том месте, где находится элемент, по клику на который и открывается форма.
Например, есть таблица, у таблицы в заголовках есть кнопки фильтров. По щелчку на кнопку фильтра появляется небольшое окошко с различными элементами ввода прямо рядом с самой кнопкой фильтра.
Что проще использовать в связке в JQuery, Bootstrap? В какую сторону копать, какой оптимальный путь решения данной задачи? Какой наиболее простой путь, решающий задачу позиционирования этого модального окна рядом с кнопкой, вызывающей его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам пока таким не занимался, но есть идея. Может просто надо при клике на элемент создавать абсолютно позиционированный div (ваше окно) и задавать ему css свойства left и rigth исходя из свойств объекта события event.target offsetLeft и offsetRigth?

Набросал [немного](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/AwdcP/)

Comment: Уже разобрался сам в принципе. Так как в проекте используется bootstrap, то буду использовать его модальные окна с измененными свойствами css. Ну и с позиционированием ничего сложного. С функцией JQuery offset() всё решается элементарно.